# Different columns in grid and in popup editor

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Is there any way how to display just a few columns in a grid and other columns as fields in editor?

Let's say that grid shows just basic information as 'ID', 'Name', 'Description' in Read-Only mode but user is able to do a full edit and popup editor show other field from data source as 'Type', 'Date', 'Category', ...

There are many ways how to hide fields from editor, but how to hide them from grid and show in editor?

Comment: set the visible property to false to the columns you want to hide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this thing by using **hidden** property of column. In below demo I have hide the UnitsInStock and UnitPrice column but it shows on popup edit window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" , hidden: true, },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px",hidden: true, },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px"  },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                        editable: "popup"
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.